# Error when making a distribution file with iPhone SDK 4.0

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, ios4

When I try to upload the binary to iTunesConnect it says: "An application targeting the iPhone device family may not require a iPhone OS Deployment Target of 3.2, which is an iPad-only OS".

I am using iPhone SDK 4.0 but have the settings of the distribution target set to use iPhone Plattform 3.2

Any suggestions?

Comment: Always read the release notes on the beta SDKs.  They indicate when you should and should not submit applications for distribution from them.  When in doubt, ask in Apple's forums: https://devforums.apple.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Stop attempting to upload apps created by a beta SDK, which is expressly forbidden.

When you have installed the correct release of the SDK, set the iPhone distribution target to one that is available on the iPhone - like 3.1.3.  If you need 3.2 support for iPad, then you also need to set the base SDK to 3.2.

Comment: The exact term to look for in the build settings is "iPhone OS Deployment Target".

Comment: I have now both SDKs installed. One for developing and one for creating the distribution file. That works.